# How to disable drag on title bar when window is maximized?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, window

The vast majority of the windows I have open are maximized. How do I disable Windows 7/10 from moving windows when I accidentally drag the mouse cursor if they're already maximized? I want to keep the drag behavior as it already is when a window is in it's "restored" state however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From vssher’s answers, after following the link to reach the desired registry key[image: this image here] There is an option for “DragFromMaximize”, if you change the value to zero, you get the desired outcome.

Also there isn’t any necessary reason to change the drag width and height or drag sensitivity.

Works on both windows 7 & 10.

Comment: I can confirm it works on 10 at least and I'll try the tweak out on my 7 machines. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @John : Half the credit goes to vssher.

Comment: ...Up-voted his post. Thank you again.

Comment: @John : You are most welcome.

Comment: @Valay_17 I appreciate that, locked my vote up on your post, goint to try it out. Windows 7 Pro 32-bit on a 64-bit processor.

Comment: "DragFromMaximize" works very well in Windows 7 Professional also, thanks to you both, Valay_17 and John. I reset my DragHeight/Width to default values (4) and your right, Valay_17, you don't need to adjust those. Thanks!

Comment: @vssher : Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

Edit the **DragHeight** and **DragWidth** in the 
Windows Registry to equal greater than the default of 4 pixels.

winhelponline.com says to change them to 50 pixels, this may be too many.

> **Source**: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-drag-drop-sensitivity-avoid-accidental-move-files/